# how to append data in nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a to add a data in a nested dictionary, where  nested keys names can be unknown so it should create new keys itself if it doesn't find one or else it should append it an existing key

this is my logic

```
 if os.path.exists(str(base_path)+"/face_encodings.pickle"):
    with open(str(base_path) + "/face_encodings.pickle", 'rb') as handle:
        faces_encodings = pickle.load(handle)
        try:
            faces_encodings[location][name] = encoding
        except:
            faces_encodings[location] = {}
            faces_encodings[location][name] = encoding
        handle.close()
        print(faces_encodings)

else:
    faces_encodings = {location:{}}
    with open(str(base_path) + "/face_encodings.pickle", 'wb') as handle:
        faces_encodings[location][name] = encoding
        pickle.dump(faces_encodings, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        handle.close()
        print(faces_encodings)
```

In brief, suppose this is a dictionary looks like

```
{
 location1:{
  id1:encoding1,
  id2:encoding2
 },
location2:{
  id3:encoding3,
  id4:encoding4
 },
location3:{
  id5:encoding5,
  id6:encoding6
 }
}
```

So by my logic code if I have to save new encoding of location which does not exist it should create a new or else push it into existing location nested dict, but the issue it's replacing the other ids data

Comment: Instead of directly doing `faces_encodings[location][name] = encoding`, first check whether location is present in the dictionary or not by `if location1 in dict1.keys()` and if yes then check for `name` in faces_encodings[location], if yes, then append it, not assign it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly,
you could check if a key exists in a dictionary using the "in" keyword. For example, if you have a dict `myDict = {"message":"Hello"}` then this statement

```py
if "message" in myDict:
   return true
else:
  return false
```

will return true.

Using this logic, you can then either 1) Create a new dict OR 2) Change the existing content of the nested dict by adding new key

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultdict` is perfect for this. It automatically creates the dict values if they don't already exist.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

d[location][name] = encoding
```

For example:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
d['giraffe']['description'] = 'tall'
d['giraffe']['legs'] = 4
d['fish']['legs'] = 0

# > defaultdict(dict,
# >            {'giraffe': {'description': 'tall', 'legs': 4},
# >             'fish': {'legs': 0}})
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping,I used defaultdict                                                                           if os.path.exists(str(base_path)+"/face_encodings.pickle"):
        with open(str(base_path) + "/face_encodings.pickle", 'rb') as handle:
            faces_encodings = defaultdict(lambda : pickle.load(handle))
            if location in faces_encodings.keys():
                if name in faces_encodings[location].keys():
                else:
                    faces_encodings[location][name] = encoding
,but its still replacing whole data,is this a wrong way to use

Comment: Please edit your post with that information, not the comment. Comments do not allow code blocks.

Comment: It looks like you've got `defaultdict(lambda: pickle.load(handle))`. You should have `defaultdict(dict)`.